# New processor woes

Tags: 14.04, cpu, bios

my motherboard is an ECS c51gm-m and the processor im trying to upgrade to is an

AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual-Core 5000+ 2.6 GHz Processor with 1024KB L2 Cache and 64-Watt Socket AM2 (ADO5000DSWOF)
by AMD

my old processor is the exact same model only its a 3800+ 2.0GHz

old processor runs great new processor gives me boot loops and freezing I know about Bios updating and honestly ive never done it before the website only supports files for windows xp which I do not have as I switched to Ubuntu fully by deleting windows 7

any ways around this I am honestly lost and had no idea where to look on here for something like this

Comment: I this the right motherboard? (look carefully) http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=653&MenuID=21&LanID=9

Comment: Can the other components, like memory, handle the higher frequency?

Comment: just upped my ram to ddr2 4gigs

Answer (score 0):

BIOS upgrades are always a fickle thing - they either work or totally brick your hardware.

What you need is a DOS compatible OS that will boot from a USB device. FreeDOS can do that.

Here's a link to do that -

```
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-install-freedos-in-usb-flash-drive-for-bios-flashing/
```

Just remember that you need to copy your BIOS patch to the same USB stick in order for FreeDOS to see it. When booted, change to C: (which will allow FreeDOS to see the USB stick as a drive), and run the patch.

BIOS upgrades used to be a nasty business, they are better now but be prepared to suffer the consequences...

Comment: there is sooo little info on how to do what you recommended it isnt even funny none of those programs are recognizing my usb drive which for some reasons isnt allowing me to format it im told this processor is supported yet i cannot safely run my computer with it and this is the first time ive considered returning to windows because of this crap

Comment: If your USB drive isn't being recognised and isn't allowing a format, then it may be faulty.